# Create column chart with sub elements for each bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts, data-visualization

I need to create a data visualization in a web application, I wanted to use Highcharts since I have some previews experience, the problem is that the visualization I need to create is more custom, based on my investigation I'd need to use something like D3 which allows to do more things, but maybe someone has done something similar using a library with a smaller learning curve.

Is it possible to create a visualization like [this](https://piktochart.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Making_Good_Looking_Charts-buiding-t2.png) (the image to the right) without using D3?[image] Each of the small boxes inside the bars is an element that should be clickable to show it's details inside a card-like HTML element.

I saw [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326337/highcharts-bar-inside-of-a-stacked-bar) with Highcharts, but it's not quite what I want and I'm not sure if what I need can also be done.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is possible in Highcharts - it would require some customization though. You need to use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer) to add custom shapes. For images, use renderer.image, for the boxes, you can use renderer.rect where each box shape depends on the column's size (col size is stored in point.shapeArgs). If you need event delegations, respnsiveness, etc. you need to implement it by yourself. POC here http://jsfiddle.net/x4rap49r/

Comment: That looks like what I need, I was more worried about the inner boxes, the fancy images are just secondary. Thanks a lot for helping.